# .Net Core 1.1.0 NuGet packages fail to install in Visual Studio Mac

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm playing around with a ASPNet.Core 1.1.0 application in Visual Studio Mac Preview and have problems updating/installing NuGet packages.

If I try to update eg. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0 it fails the download and removed the package completely. I then have to download and install the package for 1.0.0 again. Same goes for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore I'm not able to install in any version. 
Heres the exception output: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/52ceb28b8d9781835b226bcbe9d04d58

I know everything is right out of the oven, but was wondering if other people have experienced the same issues and know of a workaround/solution.

Answer (score 8):

For everyone else having similar problems, here's a walk-through:

1. First install .NET Core 1.1.0: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos
2. The official .NET Core 1.1.0 installer (as of when this is written) includes the .NET Core SDK 1.0.0 Preview 2.

You will need .NET Core SDK 1.0.0 Preview 3. Download it here: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/preview3-download.md

3. Create a new project in Visual Studio Mac
4. Close the project
5. Open up project/src/myapp/myapp.csproj and change "netcoreapp1.0" to "netcoreapp1.1". Save and close the file.

`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>`

6. Open your solution in Visual Studio Mac and compile it.

Now you will be able to update your NuGet packages to newest versions.

Should you run into problems, do a "dotnet restore" when standing in /project/src/myapp/

Comment: This got me to build and actually run, thanks for that!  For some reason I still can't update all the NuGet packages to newest versions... still get same failures.

Comment: @JasonCoder Have you tried "dotnet restore" from Console?

Comment: @egeek yes, I did.  Still can't update all the packages.  Not a deal breaker but a bit of a head scratcher

Answer (score 4):

I reached out on Twitter and got a response from Mikayla Hutchinson, Xamarin PM at Microsoft. Check out the conversation on Twitter [here](https://twitter.com/justinhhorner/status/799312322691026944).

> certain NuGet packages fail to restore if they're not already in
>   your local cache - see https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs-mac/preview/vs-mac-preview1/#Known_Issues
>
> as a workaround, you can use `dotnet restore` on the command-line,
>   which will restore and cache them

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Justin. This is a project created from within Visual Studio Mac and not through terminal with "dotnet new", so sadly "dotnet restore" won't work. I'll try to make a project through terminal and test it out.

warn : The folder '/Users/Paul/Dropbox/projects/TestNewASPNetCore/src/TestNewASPNetCore' does not contain a project to restore.

Comment: To be able to do a "dotnet restore" on a .NET Core project created in VS Mac, you need to install the .NET Core SDK 1.0.0 Preview 3. The official .Net Core 1.1.0 installer only includes SDK 1.0.0 Preview 2. 
Get the Preview 3 SDK from: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/preview3-download.md

Comment: That's it. Even for dot net core 2.0. From the terminal running dot net restore and dot net build fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change *.csproject file manually to

`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>`

**UPDATE**

@egeek So, finally, I think I found some trick. I tried to add *Swashbuckle* Nuget package, but it failed. Then, when Visual Studio start to adding *Swashbuckle*, I click Forece Quit from Visual studio before the operation is complete. In *.csproj I see:

```
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle">
  <Version>6.0.0-beta902</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

And when I again open Visual studio, click "Restore" on "Packages" folder. 
Finally it not fail and added Swashbuckle correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I already changed the Target Framework to 1.1.0 manually in csproj. You have to do this, otherwise you won't be able to run your newly created application. That's not the issue here.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! :) I imagine you can also add the package references manually in .csproj and let VS do a restore automatically when you open the project. If that don't work, doing a "dotnet restore" from Terminal should do the trick. See my answer to this post.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your nuget latest version for core 1.1 https://dist.nuget.org/index.html will resolve the issue.