# Visual Studio Mac Preview Entity Framework SQLite add migration

Tags: macos, visual-studio, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I've installed Visual Studio for Mac (OSX 10.12.1) today and I've been diving in quite extensively.

I wanted to try to get EntityFrameworkCore (1.1.0) to run with SQLite.

So I've created a new Console Application .NET Core and with some troubles been able to add all the necessary nuget packages. Somehow Visual Studio was not able to download the dependencies, so I had to download every dependency manually. (Maybe this solves the problem:  [.Net Core 1.1.0 NuGet packages fail to install in Visual Studio Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659531/net-core-1-1-0-nuget-packages-fail-to-install-in-visual-studio-mac) haven't testet this yet.)

As stated in this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite) I wanted to add the migration, but I couldn't find the necessary command line tool in the IDE. 
Did I miss something here?

Then I went on to use the .NET Core CLI to do it manually via. console. ( https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos). But when I execute `dotnet ef migrations add init` I get the following error.

> No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

Was anyone able to get this to run successfully?

Comment: I had a similar issue and was able to do a scaffold from the package manager console.  DB was PostgreSQL in my case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Visual Studio for Mac 2017 currently (April 2017) does not support adding a reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` and returns an error:

```
Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 1.0.0' has a package type 'DotnetCliTool' that is not supported by project 'MacMvc'.
```

You can edit the file manually and add the reference directly to the `csproj` file, as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet). Add this to your csproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
     <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Then run `dotnet restore` to install the package. After that, you will be able to use `dotnet ef migrations add NameOfMigration` and `dotnet ef database update` scripts as per documentation.

N.B.: you must be in the project directory when executing commands.

Also see suggestion feeedback for VS 2017 for Mac:

- https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/563332-visual-studio-for-mac/suggestions/17169425-add-sql-server-integration
- https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/563332-visual-studio-for-mac/suggestions/17138506-terminal-window

Comment: Hello miha,

Thanks for your well documented answer.
I'll try this out as soon as I get to it.

Comment: I'm still running into problems, but mainly with the dotnet cli. Thanks anyways, if I know something more, I'll extend that here.

Answer (score 2):

Using VS for Mac, adding those following lines into .csproj makes the migration work for me:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.1" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0-msbuild2-final" />
```

Packages will be automatically restored saving the .csproj from VS.

To run the "dotnet ef" command through the terminal, you need to be in the project directory, I mean not from the directory where the .sln file is, but from the lower level.

Note: Same trick with v1.0.1 of Tools.DotNet didn't work, I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have this section in your project.json file and add it if it's missing.

```
"tools": {
   "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4"
 }
```

This is valid for EF 1.1, previous version was using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` package

Comment: He is talking about Visual Studio for Mac, not Visual Studio Code. In Visual Studio for Mac there is no `project.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

Without add this ItemGroup, can't add the dbcontext scaffold connection string use of cmd, so adding this in your project (Edit .csproj) first

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this solved the issue on macOS, run this on any terminal:

`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`